# Why for loop with three dots compiles?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code which have a range of numbers from 1 to 10 but as you can see, there are 3 dots between a range. Yet still, this code compiles, but it produces no output. Am I missing something ?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for (i in 1...10) {
        println(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's clearly a bug (usability problem), so feel free to fill a report on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: it isn't a bug as much as usability.  I don't like decimals that don't have a mandatory digit to the left of the decimal separator.  ick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the .10 is probably a decimal number 0.10